# Split a graph to segments

Tags: graph-theory

To solve a programming problem, I need to  solve a graph problem, but I am weak at graph theory.

Given an undirected graph $G$ with edges $E$, I need to find $n=2$ subgraphs $G_1$ and $G_2$, so that $G_1 \cap G_2 = \emptyset $ and $G_1 \cup G_2 = G$, and the number of edges, where edge $u - v$ where $u \in G_1 $ and $v \in G_2 $ are minimal. For extra points I'm interested in alternative partiotions, other cases,  where $n>2$, or solution for weighted graphs, but they are not important.

For the curious, the programming problem is to divide a big class into smaller classes.

Comment: Select a point with minimal degree. This will be $G_1$, the rest is $G_2$. Maybe you state something about the number of vertices inside $G_k$!

Comment: @draks: That need not be minimal, e.g. two triangles joined by an edge.

Comment: Sorry, timed out, and cannot format well, so as a new comment: Suppose I have $G = \{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ and $E=\{\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{c,a\},\{d,e\},\{e,f\},\{f,d\}\}$. Your solution will cut 2 edges, but I can have $G_1=\{a,b,c\}$ and $G_2 = \{d,e,f\}$ with 0 cuts. Even if I make this graph connected with an edge $ \{c,d\} $, your solution will still miss the optimal solution.

Comment: Ok, aelguindy answered the question, but I still has some concerns. Given the following graph (that would be the case with many graphs), it is easy to cut *one* node from the graph with minimal cut. So cut e--h in {
  a--b
  b--c
  c--a

  d--e
  e--f
  f--d

  a--d
  a--d

  e--h
}
However, it is a bad refactor to split a 100 node graph to 99:1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a graph [cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28graph_theory%29), usually one means a partition of the graph into 2 parts. Computing the minimum cut for a graph can be solved using $n - 1$ max-flow computations, or even faster (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut)).

Splitting the graph into $k$ parts with the minimum number of removed edges is NP-complete (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut)). If however $k$ is constant, you can compute it in $O(|V|^{k^2})$ (see the same link).

*By the way, I am assuming that your "segments" form a partition of the graph (that is, their union is the entire graph), if not, then choose your segments to be empty sets.*

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I've fixed the question.